# Заполнение матрицы 3xN

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, матрицы

У нас есть массив чисел произвольной длины. Необходимо написать программу, результатом которой будет матрица размера 3xN, которая будет заполняться элементами массива message.
Например, message = [19, 17, 20, 9, 7], тогда матрица при N = 3 должна получиться:

```
blocks = [[19, 17, 20], 
          [9, 7, 0], 
          [0, 0, 0]]
```

N - количество элементов в подмассиве (т.е кол-во столбцов)

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь функционалом `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

message = [19, 17, 20, 9, 7]
def matrix(a: list, n: int):
    res = np.pad(a,(0, n*3-len(a)))
    return res.reshape(n,3).tolist()


print(matrix(message, 3))
```

> [[19, 17, 20], [9, 7, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

```
print(matrix([1, 4, 19, 17, 20, 9, 7], 5))
```

> [[1, 4, 19], [17, 20, 9], [7, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]